# PHP - Convert foreach to arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Anyone can help me
I have a little problem with the following code

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
   $product->name;
   $product->code;
   ...
}
```

My output code with var_dump($products)

```
array
    0 =>
      object(stdClass)
       ...
       ...
       ...
    1 =>
      object(stdClass)
       ...
       ...
       ...
```

And I need output something like this

```
$output = array(
    array('name' => 'item1', 'code' => 'code1', 'price' => '10.00'),
    array('name' => 'item2', 'code' => 'code2', 'price' => '20.00')
);
```

Comment: Can you post the exact values your going to convert into arrays?

Comment: Converting foreach to an array? You mean, converting objects to array.

Comment: If it's that you want to have arrays instead of objects you can use `(array) $whatever` and it will turn it to an array

Comment: @Xorifelse yeah probably, actually currently I'm testing Omnipay and it's need array for multiple items like ($output)->sendItems()->send();

Comment: @Rasclatt I can use if it inside foreach, but I need use it outside foreach like my above comment

Comment: @L.Herrera original values is like most common array/object so I can use like $product->name, $product->code etc if it inside foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose, there is a function is php [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth
>   = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )

Need to use this function sensibly.

As you see in the function description,

The function's three parameters:

1) Variable to be converted.

2) Return as associative array.

3) Depth: default => 512. Means upto depth of 512 levels (in case of multi-dimensional array or complex object), the child elements will be converted into arrays if second parameter is set to `true`.

First encode your variable by [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and the decode it with using 
[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) 's second parameter should be set to `true`.

This `true` means return associative array instead of original type.

Pseudo code:

```
$output = json_decode(json_encode($yourVar), TRUE);
```